# Recharge Shipping and handling amount do to glitch

Tags: invoice

We currently have been working on customizing the backend of Magento to Work for back orders. We thought we had everything in place and working and it was. The problem we noticed after a couple days is that all the invoices were not charging for Shipping. It would list the shipping charge but was not capturing the charge.

For Example: 
- Subtotal: 18.28 
 - Shipping and Handling: 20.65
 - Tax: 1.51
 - Grand Total: 19.79

As you can see the issue is that with the customization that we made tho the site. The problem is we have 50 invoices that have charges that do not include the shipping and handling in them.

I have tried setting the order state and status to many different states and statuses but have been unable to charge the remaining amount. I need to be able to charge for the shipping and handling costs of this order.

Things i have considered:

- Redoing the orders
- Reinvoicing the orders.
- Manually charging the client.
- Manipulating a partial pay extension to work.

Has anyone ran into the same issue before?

All of these I would like to avoid if someone has a theory on how I could handle it. Any help is greatly appreciated.